# Laravel 5 Send Password Reset Link using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/password/email/",
    data:{
        _token: jQuery("#forgotPasswordContainer input[name='_token']").val(),
        email: email
    },
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend:function(){

    },
    success:function(data){

    },
    complete:function(){

    }
});
```

it seems that it is doing nothing.

When I checked firebug, i am getting an html page containing the html of `/password/email` page.

I am guessing I need to modify how sending password reset link works.

Can someone help me on this matter.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Whats your php script

Comment: @HarigovindR that's the default link of Laravel when you reset a password. Therefore the PHP code is just the same when you check the file PasswordController.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solved this one by putting this on my PasswordController.php

```
public function getEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

    $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function($m)
    {
        $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });

    switch ($response)
    {
        case PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return[
                'error'=>'false',
                'msg'=>'A password link has been sent to your email address'
            ];

        case PasswordBroker::INVALID_USER:
            return[
                'error'=>'true',
                'msg'=>"We can't find a user with that email address"
            ];
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is efficient but this works for me. Hope this helps someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Laravel 5.2

If you want to customized or changed the `POST` URL that you send via `AJAX` here is the complete answer:

#### ajax.js:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/user/password/reset",
    data:{
        _token: jQuery("#forgotPasswordContainer input[name='_token']").val(),
        email: email
    },
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend:function(){

    },
    success:function(data){

    },
    complete:function(){

    }
});
```

#### routes.php:

```
Route::post('user/password/reset', [
      'uses'         => 'Controller_name@index'
]);
```

#### App/Http/Controllers/Controller_name.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;

class Controller_name extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        if( $request->ajax() )
        {
            $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

            $response = $passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'));

            switch ($response)
            {
                case PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                   return[
                       'error'=>'false',
                       'msg'=>'A password link has been sent to your email address'
                   ];

                case PasswordBroker::INVALID_USER:
                   return[
                       'error'=>'true',
                       'msg'=>"We can't find a user with that email address"
                   ];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### resources/views/

Create a new directory `auth > emails > password.blade.php` for email template:

```
Click here to reset your password .<br />
<a target="_blank" href="{{ url('password/reset', $token).'?email='.urlencode($user->getEmailForPasswordReset()) }}">Click to Reset Password</a>
```